# Regular Expression to change all instances in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a Google Maps program written so that it will provide a string of coordinates for a polyline.

Something like this:

```
(-33.26165676732799, 150.8367919921875),(-33.51849923765609, 150.22705078125),(-34.139088373438476, 149.864501953125),(-34.99850370014628, 150.0567626953125),(-35.39352808136066, 149.315185546875),(-35.69745580725804, 149.9688720703125)
```

I want to change all open parenthesis ( to the following:

new google.maps.LatLng(

with a line break in front if possible.

I have tried using regular expressions, but It will only change the first instance. I want it to change all the instances of (.

This is my last attempt:

```
var polyPath = line.getPath().getArray().toString();
var re = /^\(/g;
var polyPathFormatted = polyPath.replace(re,"new google.maps.LatLng(");
```

The "g" or at the end is not changing all of the instances, just the first one.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Why? Then you'd have to eval? Why not parse the string, then use code?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick solution:

```
var polyPath = line.getPath().getArray().toString();
var polyPathFormatted = polyPath.split("(").join("new google.maps.LatLng(");
```

Comment: Great, that works fine. Thanks, mate.  I did add <br/> to create a new line for each.